# Aptly like RPM repository

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, repository

I am currently building out infrastructure for Aptly for our Ubuntu/Debian installations. Next up I will be working on the RHEL side of things, and I want to get a good repo going that not only I need to manage.  To give you an idea, no one else here is really Unix minded.  Aptly is simple enough to manage so anything like that would be perfect.

What are you guys doing in your organization for rpm/yum repos?

Comment: [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) supports both apt and yum with a nice web GUI for administration (as well as a powerful groovy plugin system for customization). It is non-free though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few open source projects you can take a look at:

[Spacewalk](http://www.spacewalkproject.org/) and [Pulp](http://pulpproject.org/) are two projects that support RPMs, as well as other package types. You could run them in conjunction with aptly, if you like.

Alternatively, you can try using the command line tool [createrepo](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/RepoCreate) to construct your own RPM package repository.

Regardless of which option you choose, there are some important things you should be aware of when building a YUM/RPM package repository: [a createrepo bug](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2014/10/20/yum-createrepo-generate-incorrect-metadata/) and [GPG signing RPM packages and repositories](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2014/11/24/howto-gpg-sign-verify-rpm-packages-yum-repositories/).

BTW, since you mentioned APT repositories, I thought I should mention two helpful articles about [GPG signing Debian packages and APT repositories](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2014/10/28/howto-gpg-sign-verify-deb-packages-apt-repositories/), as well as a [painful APT bug](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/09/27/fixing-apt-hash-sum-mismatch-consistent-apt-repositories/) that aptly and other tools fall victim to.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I knew about Spacewalk but Pulp looks quite interesting. The two articles regarding APT/Signing will be useful to me also.

Answer (score -3):

That's the strangest question.

If I were to mention that what I'm 'doing for yum repos' is just

1) scp RPMs to location

2) run createrepo on that location

would that help?

Of course, you want to s/cp the RPMs to some place visible by the victim machines -- trivially this will mean a web resource somewhere.  You'll want to package your RPMs in the oldest distro you need, as everything's forward compatible but not backward.  Really, that's kind-of it.

But you say "no one else here is really Unix minded", but you are distributing software for Ubuntu and you want to distribute Enterprise Linux software.  Your goal is to get your devs to be Unix minded, as the wealth of security and formative issues you'll run into otherwise will be tremendous and momentous.

Truly 'doing something for yum repos' is really actually not much easier than that.  The actual actuality of it is so trivial, but the questions around it - how to package, what to package, why package - are a little trickier and ultimately as important.